# user changing last name and alias in exchange 2010

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

User wants to change her last name and alias (since the last name is part of the alias) on a network powered by Exchange Server 2010. If I change the alias from exchange console/user/properties tab, will all of her contacts and email still be there?  I guess what I'm asking is if the account is tied to the alias, user name or something else. I don't want to change it just for it act as if she's a new user. She has years worth of information in email and contacts and needs access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change her alias, just make sure you keep the old ones so old mail is forwarded to the new one.

Even if you were to mess up the mailbox won't be deleted so don't have any concerns about that. 
IF she does want to change her account name, you can simply create an email alias that points to her user account, and all messages will simply goto her 'new' email address even though they're destined for the 'old' one.

We had an issue where an intern seriously borked up our AD by running an auto-account name script. No one lost access to anything, they just didn't know what their new usernames were.

Comment: Since she wants to have her old alias active for awhile to allow time for everyone to be updated on her new email address, would it work to change her alias and then add that to a new distribution group with her her old name?  I was thinking that way people would still be able to send email to her old address and it will be forwarded to her new one.  After a time I could just delete the distribution group to finalize the conversion. Will this work or would that cause a problem I don't yet see?

Comment: That would work, and I don't see any realy problem with it. I would simply change her alias, but leave her old Email alias so she still gets those emails. Create the new email alias to whatever she prefers, then have her alert everyone that she is changing email addresses. This way you can just phase the old email address out with actually removing anything other than a reference...or just leave the old one, just in case(which is what I would do)